# How to access single items in a list with a lenght of 1?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have imported a json file and converted it to a python dict. From there I extracted the dict I needed and imported it into a list. Now I would like to manipulate the items further, for example only extract 'player_fullname' : 'Lenny Hampel'. However, it seems that there is another dict inside the list, which len is 1, and I cannot access it.

**[image: My Question: How can i extract or add items into that list/dict, so I can manipulate them further?]**

Comment: looks to me as there is a list with a dict inside. not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a list with 1 entry and the entry is the dict. Easiest way would be:

```
player = player[0] #get the dict
print(player['player_fullname'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `player_fullname` whether in your dict and then compare name value.

```
[item for item in your_dict if item.get('player_fullname', '') == 'Lenny Hampel']
```